# Select múltiple bootstrap

Tags: php, html, html5, json, bootstrap

Buenas noches,

Compañeros tengo una pequeña inquietud. Tengo un archivo PHP donde estoy usando bootstrap y tengo un DIV con varios inputs y select, mediante un botón llamará una función en Javascript donde enviará la información de esos campos para posteriormente almacenar en una base de datos en MongoDB. Esto para aclarar que no estoy haciendo uso de la etiqueta form.

Ahora bien, quiero saber cómo incorporar un select múltiple como esos de que primero eliges la provincia y luego dependiendo de la provincia te despliega las ciudades en otro select. Soy de Colombia y la cuestión sería departamentos y que despliegue ciudades, encontré un JSON que pueda ser de ayuda. Para saber si me pueden colaborar gracias.

https://github.com/marcovega/colombia-json/blob/master/colombia.json

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer lo que buscas, debes seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. Escuchar el evento `change` del `select` principal
2. Dependiendo del valor de dicho select en cada evento `change`, realizar una llamada `Ajax` o tomar los datos de algún objeto local
3. Dependiendo del resultado de tu llamada `Ajax` o los datos del objeto local, debes decidir qué hacer en el siguiente paso. Si el retorno es una cadena `HTML` con las opciones que deben ir en el `select` secundario, solamente debes insertar el resultado dentro del mismo usando [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). Si el resultado es un objeto u `array` con las opciones, deberás insertar las opciones dinámicamente dentro del select secundario.

Por ejemplo, observa el siguiente *snippet*. En el mismo estoy haciendo una petición `Ajax` usando [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) cada vez que se varía el `select` principal, y con los resultados de esa llamada, relleno el `select` secundario creando las opciones dinámicamente. Creo que esto te puede dar una idea de cómo afrontar tu problema:

```js
const asunto = document.getElementById('asunto');
const subasunto = document.getElementById('subasunto');
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/';
const labels = {
  users: 'name',
  todos: 'title',
  albums: 'title'
};

const clearSelect = () => {
  const options = subasunto.querySelectorAll('option:not([value=""])');
  options.forEach(option => subasunto.removeChild(option));
};

const fillSelect = (asunto, json) => {
  json.forEach(item => {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = item.id;
    option.innerText = item[labels[asunto]];
    subasunto.appendChild(option);
  });
  subasunto.disabled = false;
};

asunto.addEventListener('change', () => {
  clearSelect();
  subasunto.disabled = true;
  const value = asunto.value;
  if (value) {
    fetch(`${url}${value}`)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(json => fillSelect(value, json));
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="asunto">
  <option value="">Selecciona</option>
  <option value="users">Usuarios</option>
  <option value="todos">Tareas</option>
  <option value="albums">Álbumes</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="subasunto" disabled>
  <option value="">Selecciona</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas se llaman "Combos dependientes". Como bien indica el nombre, estos dependen de la opción que selecciones.

Aquí te dejo un enlace para que puedas ver como funcionan: https://www.jose-aguilar.com/blog/combos-dependientes-con-jquery-ajax-y-php/

Este ejemplo se realiza con php, pero puedes realizarlo con json también.